# How to find how many hours an Android phone has been used?

Tags: settings, dialer-codes

I want to know if there is a method that can tell me how many hours an Android phone has been used. Just like we have cheat codes that we used for Nokia phones; they tell us the hours (regardless of factory reset). Any alternate for Android?

Comment: Cheat codes? `*#*#4636#*#*` might give you the details you are looking for. And of course there are more cheat codes available...

Comment: @Izzy - That code doesn't appear to work on Samsung phones.  At least, it doesn't on my stock Galaxy S3 .

Comment: Oops? First time I hear it's not working on some device! Sorry for that! Just tested on a Galaxy Ace 2 (stock Android 2.3): Works fine there.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Settings → About phone → Status, 
scroll to bottom and you will be able to see Up time.

I think this feature is available on Android 4+.

Comment: For some reason on my Android 9 Mi A1 I can no longer find the option. Which is curious (I had it before, though not sure if on Pie).

Comment: This gives uptime since last boot, nothing to do with how long a handset has been used for.

Answer (score 1):

Try typing this code in your dialer: `##786#` or `*#*#786#*#*`

If that doesn't work, install "Launcher Pro". That app can show you hidden menus of your phone, which are the same menus that those two dialer codes should bring up.

Comment: This might be hard reset according to the blog [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Nexus5/comments/2e9wns/hey_guys_does_anyone_have_a_list_of_ussd_codes/). And Uptime always resets once you restart the phone. [Edited by Moderator Firelord]

Comment: For which Android version(s) does the code works? Doesn't work on my CM12.

Comment: Seems to be model/brand specific...

Answer (score 0):

[QualityTime](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zerodesktop.appdetox.qualitytime) is a good app that can track how long you use your device daily and weekly. It can also track how long you use individual apps.